# Alternative to "waiting period"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I cannot find an alternative to name this concept: In a negotiation process, after a proposal is presented, time is left for the parties to comment on or object to it.

"Waiting period" alludes to the view of the party who brought the proposal and suggests passivity. Is there a term or an expression which would describe this period more positively?

("Grace period" was a candidate, but its meaning seems too remote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a *comment period*.

For example, government agencies are usually required to have a comment period when [proposing new rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rulemaking).

> **Public comment.** Once a proposed rule is published in the Federal Register, a public comment period begins, allowing the public to submit written comments to the agency. Most agencies are required to respond to every issue raised in the comments. Depending on the complexity of the rule, comment periods may last for 30 to even 180 days.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest **"evaluation period" or "appraisal stage"**

> - appraisal - "the act of judging the value, condition, or importance of something : the act of appraising something" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appraisal)
> - evaluation - "the act of determining the importance, effectiveness, or worth of" [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evaluation)

Answer (score 0):

What about -

**[cooling-off period](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/cooling-off-period.html)**

[**period of time during which the purchaser may cancel a purchase.**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooling-off_period)
 (wiki)

- after a proposal is presented, time left for the parties to comment on or object to it.